# How to create a vector of a specific class in c++ that includes thread objects in it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, vector, pthreads

I have created a class named AnalyzerCore in c++ like below:

AnalyzerCore.h

```
class AnalyzerCore
{
private:
    thread AnalyzerThread;
    void AnalyzerFunc();
    bool isRunning;
    int id;

public:
    AnalyzerCore(int id_in);
    ~AnalyzerCore();
};
```

AnalyzerCore.cpp

```
void AnalyzerCore::AnalyzerFunc()
{
    while (isRunning) {
        cout << "Analyzer "<< id << " is active!\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

AnalyzerCore::AnalyzerCore(int id_in)
{
    id = id_in;
    isRunning = true;
    AnalyzerThread = thread(&AnalyzerCore::AnalyzerFunc, this);
}

AnalyzerCore::~AnalyzerCore()
{
    isRunning = false;
    if (AnalyzerThread.joinable()) AnalyzerThread.join();
}
```

and in the main.cpp, I have maked a vector of AnalyzerCore and push_back 2 instance of the calss

```
int main()
{
    vector<AnalyzerCore> a;
    a.push_back(AnalyzerCore(0));
    a.push_back(AnalyzerCore(1));
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

But when I have built above, I have faced following error:

> 'AnalyzerCore::AnalyzerCore(const AnalyzerCore &)': attempting to
> reference a deleted function

What's wrong with my code and what do you suggest to fix it?
thank you!

Comment: You need to define move constructor and move assignment for your class with meaningful semantics. See rule-of-0/3/5. (In your case you probably want to leave the copy operations deleted, since there is no meaning in copying a thread usually).

Comment: I guess the semantics that you want in your case are either the default ones, so `= default` both move operations, or a modification that sets `isRunning` to `false` in the source.

Comment: FYI: `AnalyzerCore::~AnalyzerCore()` -- `AnalyzerThread.join()` can throw an exception.  Throwing exceptions in a destructor can terminate your application.  You shouldn't allow exceptions to escape the destructor -- your destructor code should be wrapped in a `try/catch`.

Comment: Would you consider embedding a `std::shared_ptr<thread>` in your `AnalyzerCore` class instead of trying to embed a `thread`?

Comment: @user17732522 the program run without error but the value of id has changed to -572662307 for the first instance of class, the second is true. I used emplace_back instead of push_back.

Comment: @lord-hasan Then you didn't implement the move operations correctly. Also, `emplace_back` or `push_back` won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy a `std::thread` (what would that mean?), hence you cannot copy a `AnalyzerCore`.

You can use `std::vector::emplace_back()` to construct the `AnalyzerCore` objects directly in the vector, rather than constructing a temporary and then copying or moving it into the vector.

Moreover, when the vector grows, it has to reallocate and move or copy elements. As you cannot copy, you need to add a move constructor (when the compiler does not generate it):

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    std::thread t;
    int value;
    foo(int value) : value(value) {}
    foo(foo&&) = default;
    ~foo(){}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> ts;
    ts.emplace_back(42);
    ts.emplace_back(42);
    ts.emplace_back(42);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h4PK9174q)

Comment: I checked your idea but the problem still persists.

Comment: @lord-hasan calling `emplace(0)`  should not cause an error about a missing copy constructor, because no copy is made. If you call `emplace(AnalyzerCore(1))` then thats a wrong use of `emplace` and a copy is made

Comment: @lord-hasan you can show me how the problem persists eg here https://godbolt.org/z/3rTc3oYnf.

Comment: @463035818-is-not-an-ai Can you define a class with a destructor. When I add a destructor to my class compiler got an error.

Comment: @lord-hasan yeah sory, my example was too simplified. If you had posted a [mcve] I would have copied it, but as you didnt I started fresh example that did have a compiler generated move constructor. Especially, a user declared destructor prevents the compiler to generate a move constructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai "*rather than constructing a temporary and then copying it into the vector*" - `push_back` is overloaded to move the temporary, not copy it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I still have issues with wording regarding move semantics. I know its somewhat off, but to my understanding if you have a temporary and you move or copy it what you get is a *copy* and whether it was moved or copied isnt actually that relevant. I mean the difference between copy or move is in the source, but when its a temporary you wont see the difference on the source. Whats the word for "copy or move" ? cove? mopy?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Move semantics were invented especially to handle temporaries more effectively by moving data out of them without making copies.

Answer (score 1):

First off, switch all the `push_back(AnalyzerCore(x))` calls to `emplace_back(x)`. This will force the `std::vector` to call the `AnalyzerCore(AnalyzerCore&&)` constructor rather than the `AnalyzerCore(const AnalyzerCore&)` constructor. (The former takes an xvalue, and the latter takes a lvalue - see [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/))

`std::vector` requires this to be explicitly defined for it to accept your class.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class AnalyzerCore
{
private:
    std::thread AnalyzerThread;
    void AnalyzerFunc();
    bool isRunning;
    int id;

public:
    AnalyzerCore(int id_in);

    AnalyzerCore(const AnalyzerCore&) = delete;
    AnalyzerCore(AnalyzerCore&&) = default;

    ~AnalyzerCore();
};
```

As soon as you define any constructor, all other default constructors that would have made your class valid for `std::vector`'s type traits are removed.

To remove support for copying, add the `= delete;` constructor.

To add support for xvalue copying, add the `&&) = default;` for the default xvalue constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The program run without error but the value of id has changed to -572662307 for the first instance of class,  when the second instance was emplaced. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think when I emplaced back second element, the destructor of first element was called.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `push_back` or `emplace_back`. They will both use the move operations (if they were declared).

Comment: @lord-hasan You are doing something wrong to check the `id` then. The code shown here won't change the value of any `id` to that one.